# Creating Java Restful webservice on Windows Azure

Tags: java, web-services, rest, azure

we are working on our graduation project project that has two main block

1- A **website** that is written in ASP.NET

2- A **webservice** that access the database (mySQL DB) , do some processing on data and communicate with that website to show the results.

We are using a java library [Apache Mahout] in that webservice to help us do that processing and that's why we need to write this webservice in JAVA

How can we create and host a Restful java webservice on Windows Azure ? What are the available options ?

Also , Is it possible to start the processing and stop it depending on a request that is sent from the website or another block (another webservice for example) ?

I hope the situation is now clear.I would appreciate if you could provide us with any resources that could help us understand how Restful java Webservice in Azure works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today you have two options for running Java on Windows Azure:  Cloud Services and Virtual Machines.  Cloud Services (Platform as a Service) enable you to package up a web deployment (WAR) along with a JDK and your java server of choice (Jetty, tomcat, Jboss, etc) and deploy it.  Your other option is to use a virtual machine (Infrastructure as a Service).  You have a few different options for virtual machines (including officially supported Oracle images: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/campaigns/oracle/).

Your easiest option will be looking at Cloud Services (though this does require packaging no a Windows computer).  There is a great Windows Azure plugin for Eclipse that will help you out tremendously (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694271.aspx).  There are also a lot of tutorials, resources, and links to references here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/.

Comment: Can we apply this on Restful services too , I'm sorry but I don't have previous knowledge in webservices field.

If I want to start building my restful webservice that would be deployed as a cloud service , from where should I start ? Thanks for answering my question quickly :)

Comment: Building RESTful services isn't something that's really specific to Azure.  I would spend some time researching how to build RESTful services with Java.  Once you've figured out how to do that, it's really just a matter of packaging what you're building into an Azure deployment with the Eclipse tooling.  I presume that you're doing the service in Java because of your project but if you aren't limited you Java, you could also look at building the web service with Web API and .NET.

Comment: what about mySQL database ? Can I use a cloud service and still be able to use mySQL to store and retrieve my data.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if MySQL has IP range restrictions or anything like that but you would just need to make sure your cloud service can get through to the MySQL database.

Comment: I meant a mySQL db that is also hosted in Windows Azure , as far as I know , I can create a mySQL db on Windows Azure through ClearDB MySQL DB. I'm sorry for asking many questions , I hope I'm not annoying you Sir

Comment: That's correct. Within the Windows Azure Portal I "believe" the only way to create a MySQL DB is to do it at the same time as a new Windows Azure Website, however, you should be able to go to ClearDB and create a DB and then connect to it from your Cloud Service (https://www.cleardb.com/store/azure).

Answer (score 2):

Azure websites now supports Java web applications - check it out - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/ - you use the default JDK 7 with Tomcat 7.0.50 or Jetty 9.1.0 OR you can even upload your own web container and configure it as per your requirements. Please refer to the link above.

I have created a Java web service using Axis2 Framework/Eclipse and deployed it on Azure Websites.